# How to group_by date to show counts of zero and non zero entries?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following sample data.
I am trying to group them in the the various dates and I need new columns to tell me how many zero entries and how many non-zero entries.

```
gantry_date gantry_duration
10/2/2018   126.809
10/2/2018   0
10/2/2018   38.505
10/2/2018   0
10/2/2018   63.888
10/2/2018   81.362
10/2/2018   45.055
10/1/2018   111.648
10/1/2018   0
10/1/2018   119.291
10/1/2018   0
10/1/2018   37.565
10/1/2018   33.794
10/1/2018   0
10/1/2018   0
10/1/2018   0
```

desired output is

```
         Zero   non-zero
10/1/2018   5   4
10/2/2019   2   5
```

I tried the following codes with different permutation of XXXX. Tried summarize, count, sum and a combination of summarize and sum or count.

```
data <- gantry1 %>% group_by(gantry_date) %>% XXXXX
```

could not get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `table`

```
table(df$gantry_date, df$gantry_duration == 0)

#            FALSE TRUE
#  10/1/2018     4    5
#  10/2/2018     5    2
```

If you want the exact names, maybe we can add a new column

```
df$status <- c("zero", "non-zero")[(df$gantry_duration != 0) + 1]
table(df$gantry_date, df$status)
#            non-zero zero
#  10/1/2018        4    5
#  10/2/2018        5    2
```

---

A `tidyverse` way would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(status =  c("zero", "non-zero")[(gantry_duration != 0) + 1]) %>%
  count(gantry_date, status) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = n)
```